# SES Email not verified for "to" field in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, laravel-5, amazon-ses

I have:

```
Mail::send('emails.booking-confirmation', [
        'name' => $name,
        'email' => $email,
        'tel' => $tel,
        'msg' => $msg,
        'date' => Carbon::parse($date)->format('l, jS \o\f F, Y \a\t H:ia'),
        'service' => $q->service,
        'duration' => $q->duration . ' minutes'
    ], function ($m) use ($name, $email) {
        $m->from('myemail@ddress.co.uk', 'Subject');
        $m->to($email, $name)->subject('Your Booking');
    });
```

When sending using AWS SES I get:

```
Error executing "SendRawEmail" on "https://email.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com"; AWS HTTP error: Client error: `POST https://email.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response:
<ErrorResponse xmlns="http://ses.amazonaws.com/doc/2010-12-01/">
<Error>
<Type>Sender</Type>
<Code>MessageReje (truncated...)
MessageRejected (client): Email address is not verified. - <ErrorResponse xmlns="http://ses.amazonaws.com/doc/2010-12-01/">
<Error>
<Type>Sender</Type>
<Code>MessageRejected</Code>
<Message>Email address is not verified.</Message>
</Error>
<RequestId>8551cf11-f420-11e5-b4ac-bf30e6ff71ee</RequestId>
</ErrorResponse>
```

My address and domain are verified.

If I do:

```
...
], function ($m) use ($name, $email) {
        $m->from('myemail@ddress.co.uk', 'Subject');
        $m->to('myemail@ddress.co.uk', $name)->subject('Your Booking');
    });
```

It works perfectly, but is completely useless.

How do I get this working so I can send email to users who fill out my form?

Comment: Out of interest, what is the output of `var_dump($email); die()` just before `$m->to($email, $name)->subject('Your Booking');` ?

Comment: @Chris string 'users@email.com' (length=18)

Comment: I'm just being a sounding board here - but if you copy paste in manually, so like your second example: $m->to('users@email.com', $name)->subject('Your Booking'); Does that work?

Comment: @Chris No, I get the error.

Comment: Again just brainstorming - is it possible your my@address.co.uk is working, but a `@email` is not because its some kind of reserved domain?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is complaining your `To: email` address is not verified. Looks like you are in `SES Sandbox` mode. Until you change your SES account to `production` account, you have to verify your `Sender` email address too.

When you tested both `From` and `To` are your email address (which is already verified).

From: [Verifying Email Addresses in Amazon SES](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/verify-email-addresses.html)

> Until your account is out of the Amazon SES sandbox, you must also
>   verify the email address of every recipient except for the recipients
>   provided by the Amazon SES mailbox simulator. For more information
>   about the mailbox simulator, see Testing Amazon SES Email Sending. For
>   more information about moving out of the sandbox, see Moving Out of
>   the Amazon SES Sandbox.

[Moving Out of the Amazon SES Sandbox](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/request-production-access.html)