# Amazon SES error on VERIFIED domain and EMAIL, correct region (Laravel)

Tags: amazon-web-services, laravel-5, amazon-ses

Trying to send email through Amazon SES. Both the domains and email **are** verified, **account is out of the sandbox** (have been using it without problems a while ago), and the reqion **is** set correctly. trying it from Laravel 5.4

right now is

```
SesException in WrappedHttpHandler.php line 192:
    Error executing "SendRawEmail" on "https://email.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com"; AWS HTTP error: Client error: `POST https://email.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response:
<ErrorResponse xmlns="http://ses.amazonaws.com/doc/2010-12-01/">
<Error>
<Type>Sender</Type>
<Code>MessageReje (truncated...)
MessageRejected (client): Email address is not verified. The following 
identities failed the check in region EU-WEST-1: service@civilhang.ro - 
<ErrorResponse xmlns="http://ses.amazonaws.com/doc/2010-12-01/">
<Error>
<Type>Sender</Type>
<Code>MessageRejected</Code>
<Message>Email address is not verified. The following identities failed the 
 check in region EU-WEST-1: service@civilhang.ro</Message>
</Error>
<RequestId>82e11e14-c1fc-11e7-9836-57d1bfe12a45</RequestId>
</ErrorResponse>
```

[image]

does anyone have any clue?

Comment: SES regions are (mostly) independent.  The address must be verified in the region you're connecting to.  Check this?  You're invoking eu-west-1.  Is that where you're verified?

Comment: yessss, it is verified, i checkid it for 1000 times. keepm in mind that this worked for quite a bit, and i didnt modified a thing. just noticed that suddenly no mails are passed.

Answer (score 3):

I know that this is fairly old, but this fixed my issue.

> It is complaining your To: email address is not verified. Looks like you are in SES Sandbox mode. Until you change your SES account to production account, you have to verify your Sender email address too.
>   When you tested both From and To are your email address (which is already verified).
>   From: Verifying Email Addresses in Amazon SES
>   Until your account is out of the Amazon SES sandbox, you must also verify the email address of every recipient except for the recipients provided by the Amazon SES mailbox simulator. For more information about the mailbox simulator, see Testing Amazon SES Email Sending. For more information about moving out of the sandbox, see Moving Out of the Amazon SES Sandbox.
>   [Moving Out of the Amazon SES Sandbox](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/request-production-access.html)

Reference: [SES Email not verified for "to" field in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36247957/ses-email-not-verified-for-to-field-in-laravel/36248503#36248503)

Hope you have a great day!

Comment: i hope this answer will help me sending emails. as it was working few days back. but now I see this error.

Answer (score 1):

One thing pops to mind is that you have several aws accounts configured you are not using the correct account.

My suggestion is to rotate your existing AWS key and update your Laravel configuration file and see if you get the same error.

Or try entering the wrong AWS AccessKey.

As far as I can tell, the error is a standard error and my only conclusion is that the keys you are using are not bound to that account.

Comment: tried using wrong key (on purpose), the error message is different (the process fails at the auth level, before sending)

Comment: How about creating a new keypair? Or a new user and a new keypair for the new user?

Comment: got to try it and inform you, just for curiosity... :)